# How to sort the column in ascending order in R

Tags: r

I want to make my column(date) in an ascending order.

I tried below but it didnt worked.

```
data3 <- data2[order(data2$date_1,decreasing = FALSE)]
```

It gave me this error:--

> Error in [.data.frame(data2, order(data2$date_1, decreasing = FALSE)) : 
>     undefined columns selected

my data is

```
Sr. date_1 No_of_births  
1   1   40255  
2   10  41874  
3   11  38940  
4   12  40320  
5   2   36428  
6   3   39940  
7   4   37641  
8   5   39288  
9   6   38789  
10  7   42148  
11  8   42980  
12  9   42112
```

The output i want is as below with other columns also.
(((just showing date column)))

```
Date

1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9  
10  
11  
12
```

Comment: You're just missing a comma, bolded here: `data3 <- data2[order(data2$date_1,decreasing = FALSE)` **`,`** `]`. Subsetting data frames with `[` can happen two ways: `data[columns]` or `data[rows, columns]`. Because you didn't use any commas, it was trying to pick out specific columns. Because you have more rows than columns, it was trying to pick columns that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `data3 <- data2[order(as.integer(data2$date_1),decreasing = FALSE), ]`

Plus:

It is a good idea to check `class(date2$date_1)` before using `order`. It this data are of class `integer` or `numeric`, then you have 1, 2, 3, ..., 10, 11, ...; However, it is `character`, then without casting/coercing it into integer, you get "1", "10", "11", "12", ... "2".

Answer (score 5):

Easy `dplyr` solution:

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library('dplyr')

data3 <- arrange(data2, date)
```